# Download a File From Remote Server -- Without Virtual Directory and IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I wanted to download a document from our remote server. But we don't want to create a virtual directory to the document location and expose the document as URL.

I know if we create a virtual directory, then we can definitely download the file using "WebClient" or "HttpWebRequest" class. But we can't create a virtual directory in our remote server.

Is there any other approach?

Comment: Do you mean without IIS? Because that is a bit confusing.

Comment: Have remote server read the file from local directory in its own ASP.NET code and write binary to the client. Then your client code can just reference that page

Comment: You should provide more details on what task(s) (and which conditions, like environment, client etc.) you would expect to use. As that's really a problem to get to someone's machine without any 'access points' to get some info from there, unless you have something additional set up on that server. So, the question is what are the possibilities/technologies you can use on the server side.

Comment: Then only method that comes in my mind is, via ftp but you need credentials.

Comment: I can share the folder to a specific User Name and Pass on the remote server. Will that help?

Comment: If you don't want to "expose the document as URL", then what you're really talking about is not allowing access via HTTP. So, just pick your favorite other protocol that can handle file transfer: FTP, SFTP (really just SSH), etc.